# forge retrieve (translation/publish) item date

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

i am wondering if there is an API that retrieves  the (translation/publish) date:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the last version of that item by calling [GET Folder Contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/), [GET items/:itemId](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/), or [GET item/:itemId/versions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/), and find `attributes.lastModifiedTime`, then convert it from UTC time to your localtime. Here is an example for you:

```json
"included": [
    {
      "type": "versions",
      "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.hC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w?version=2",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "my_model.rvt",
        "displayName": "my_model",
        "createTime": "2018-01-17T11:52:34.0000000Z",
        "createUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "createUserName": "John Doe",
        "lastModifiedTime": "2018-01-17T11:53:20.0000000Z", //!<<< Here
        "lastModifiedUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "lastModifiedUserName": "John Doe",
        "versionNumber": 2,
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
        "fileType": "rvt",
        "extension": {
          "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "schema": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel-1.0.0"
          },

          //...
    },

    //...

],
```

Comment: super, my problem was with the time differences that i am seeing it an hour before, however, i fix it with little code :)
thanks Eason Kang :))